# How to make the TextField widget editable when using controller as TextEditingController(text:"Enter value")?

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, textfield, provider

I have been trying to make the initial text passed through `controller:TextEditingController(text:"Enter DOB")` inside a `TextField` widget in `Flutter` **editable**, but I can't find any solution(for now).

I want to make the `selectedDate`(or the initial text) editable after selecting a date from the `showDatePicker` method  inside the `TextField`.

SO I NEED SOME HELP HERE. Is there a way to do it??

Following is my code. I want to make the text in the controller editable.

```
     TextField(
              // This controller will show the initial value as 'Enter DOB'
              // and when the Date is selected from the showDatePicker it will
              // get updated.
              controller: TextEditingController(
                // the text: property will check if the current value is null or not.
                // if null it will show the "Enter your DOB" text, else the selected## Heading ##Date
                // will get updated.
                text: validator.selectedDate == null
                    ? "Enter your DOB"
                    : "${validator.selectedDate}".split(' ')[0],
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today_rounded),
                  onPressed: () {
                    validator.selectDate(context);
                  },
                ),
                labelText: "yyyy-mm-dd",
              ),

              onChanged: (String value) {
                validator.changeDOB(value);
              },
            );
```

Where,

- `selectedDate` is a variable of type `DateTime` having an initial value as `null`.
- `selectDate(BuildContext context)` is a method with `showDatePicker(BuildContext context)` method.
- `changeDOB(String value)` is a method which will update the `selectedDate` value to the `TextField`.

**NOTE**: ***I am using the `Provider` as a state-management approach.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I have solved my problem the above answer gave me an idea to do it.

- I just declared a `TextEditingController()..text="Enter DOB"` variable and passed it to the `showDatePicker(BuildContext context)` method.
- And from there I fed the `controller.text` with the value of `selectedDate.toString().split(' ')[0]`.
- And also the called `changeDOB(controller.text)` with `controller.text` as an argument.
- Following is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyClass with ChangeNotifier {
  // passing the initial text to the textField through controller.
  var controller = TextEditingController()..text = "Enter DOB";

  DateTime selectedDate; // initial value = null;
  selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    var picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(1800),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      selectedDate = picked;
      // passing the selectedDate to the controller.
      controller.text = selectedDate.toString().split(' ')[0];
      changeDOB(controller.text);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
   void changeDOB(String value){
     //TODO: Your validation logic here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make `TextEditingController` as local variable and then change it with `setState()`

It's something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DateTimeExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DateTimeExampleState createState() => _DateTimeExampleState();
}

class _DateTimeExampleState extends State<DateTimeExample> {

  TextEditingController _dobController; // Local variable to store TextFiled text

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Initialize TextEditingController object with default text.
    _dobController = TextEditingController(text: "Enter your DOB: ");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( 
      body:Container(
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _dobController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today_rounded),
                onPressed: () {
                  String selectedDate=  validator.selectDate(context);
                  setState(() {
                  _dobController.text = selectedDate; // Change the text and refersh UI
                  });
                },
              ),
              labelText: "YYYY-MM-DD",
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              validator.changeDOB(value);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: Must your `validator.selecteDate(Context)` function return a `String` so it can refresh you state.

Comment: Thank you so much... Your answer gave me an idea to implement the problem I had.

Comment: thank you please accept my answer to boost my reputation